Frame-Motion package breaks a flexed material-react-table
I have a Material-UI 5 Card containing a Material React table (https://v1.material-react-table.com/). I want the table to occupy the entire remaining space within the Card. This is worked with some properties inside the table i.e. set to flex  (photo1).

The issue arises when I use the framer-motion package to animate this card.
When motion is enabled i.e <m.div initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }}> the table disappears (photo2).

Here a sample of my code
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { MaterialReactTable } from 'material-react-table';

// mui
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';

import { m, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';

const data = [
   {
      name: 'John',
      surname: 'Maverick',
      xxx: 'test',
      yyy: 'test',
      zzz: 'test',
      age: 30,
      salary: 10000,
   },
   {
      name: 'John',
      surname: 'Maverick',
      xxx: 'test',
      yyy: 'test',
      zzz: 'test',
      age: 30,
      salary: 10000,
   },
   {
      name: 'John',
      surname: 'Maverick',
      xxx: 'test',
      yyy: 'test',
      zzz: 'test',
      age: 30,
      salary: 10000,
   },
   {
      name: 'John',
      surname: 'Maverick',
      xxx: 'test',
      yyy: 'test',
      zzz: 'test',
      age: 30,
      salary: 10000,
   },
];

const TasksDashboard = () => {
   const columns = useMemo(
      () => [
         {
            accessorKey: 'name',
            header: 'Name',
            minSize: 300,
            muiTableHeadCellProps: { sx: { color: 'green' } },
            Cell: ({ renderedCellValue }) => <strong>{renderedCellValue}</strong>,
         },
         {
            accessorKey: 'surname',
            header: 'surname',
            minSize: 300,
         },
         {
            accessorKey: 'xxx',
            header: 'xxx',
            minSize: 300,
         },
         {
            accessorKey: 'zzz',
            header: 'zzz',
            minSize: 300,
         },
         {
            accessorKey: 'yyy',
            header: 'yyy',
            minSize: 300,
         },
         {
            accessorFn: (row) => `${row.age}`,
            id: 'age',
            header: 'Age',
            Header: <i style={{ color: 'red' }}>Age</i>,
            filterVariant: 'range-slider',
            muiTableHeadCellFilterSliderProps: {
               marks: false,
               max: 100000,
               min: -100000,
               step: 1000,
            },
            Footer: <i style={{ color: 'red' }}>Age</i>,
            muiTableHeadCellProps: {
               align: 'right',
            },
            muiTableBodyCellProps: {
               align: 'right',
            },
            muiTableFooterCellProps: {
               align: 'right',
            },
            maxSize: 200,
         },
         {
            accessorKey: 'salary',
            header: 'Salary',
            muiTableHeadCellProps: { sx: { color: 'green' } },
            maxSize: 200,
            muiTableBodyCellProps: {
               align: 'right',
            },
            muiTableFooterCellProps: {
               align: 'right',
            },
         },
         {
            header: 'Age + Salary',
            id: 'mutlilineTest',
            accessorFn: (row) => `${row.age} ${row.salary}`,
            muiTableHeadCellProps: { sx: { color: 'blue' }, align: 'right' },
            Cell: ({ renderedCellValue }) => <strong>{renderedCellValue}</strong>,
            maxSize: 200,
            muiTableBodyCellProps: {
               align: 'right',
            },
            muiTableFooterCellProps: {
               align: 'right',
            },
         },
      ],
      []
   );

   return (
      <Container component={AnimatePresence} maxWidth={false} disableGutters sx={{ height: '100%' }}>
         <Card sx={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', position: 'relative' }}>
            <m.div initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }}>
               <div>HEADER </div>
               <div>HEADER</div>
               <div>HEADER</div>
               <div>HEADER</div>
               <div>HEADER</div>
               <div>--------</div>
               <MaterialReactTable
                  columns={columns}
                  data={data}
                  enableFullScreenToggle={false}
                  initialState={{ showGlobalFilter: true }}
                  muiSearchTextFieldProps={{
                     variant: 'outlined',
                     size: 'small',
                  }}
                  positionGlobalFilter="left"
                  enableSorting={false}
                  enableGlobalFilter
                  enableColumnFilters
                  enableColumnResizing
                  enableStickyHeader
                  enableStickyFooter
                  muiTablePaperProps={{
                     sx: {
                        flex: '1 1 0',
                        display: 'flex',
                        'flex-flow': 'column',
                     },
                  }}
                  muiTableContainerProps={{
                     sx: {
                        flex: '1 1 0',
                     },
                  }}
               />
            </m.div>
         </Card>
      </Container>
   );
};

TasksDashboard.propTypes = {};
export default TasksDashboard;

I think the issue with the framer-motion is related to the height of the table. I'm struggling to find an alternative approach to achieve the desired maximized height effect to my table. Any recommendations?
